# Can an ability be raised above 5?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade

I started a Roll20 campaign for Vampire: The Masquerade (20th Anniversary Edition) and I noticed that in the ability block, abilities can be raised above 5 (6-10). Is it actually possible to do so using the rules from the book?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The limit on disciplines, abilities, and attributes is set by a vampire's Generation. If you are of the 7th generation or older, those numbers can exceed 5 dots. (p.270, V20 core rule book.)